# How much faster is the Millennium Falcon compared to a YT-1300?

Tags: star-wars, millennium-falcon

We know Solo made some "special modifications" to the Millennium Falcon, but how much faster does it go compared to an (original, "off the shelf") YT-1300?

Comment: About 3000 yots faster.

Comment: Less than 12 parsecs?

Answer (score 7):

The [Starlog Technical Journal (Part 1)](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Technical_Journal_of_the_Planet_Tatooine) indicates that the stock YT-1300 only had a standard **light-speed plus point one hyperdrive** as opposed to the souped-up "light-speed plus point *five* hyperdrive" that Han boasts of in Star Wars: A New Hope. Quite what the speed *differential* actually is isn't explained in any great detail.

> The Millennium Falcon's power, propulsion and computer network
>   arrangements require a constant maintenance schedule that keeps her
>   repair and adjustment time at a level nearly twice the ship's flying
>   time. Solo regards the trade-off as well worth it, for more than once
>   his life has been saved by his ship's speed and extreme
>   manoeuvrability. A beefed-up hyperdrive system is at the core of the
>   Falcon's increased speed, which is well above the light-speed plus
>   point one capability of the standard Corellian YT-1300. Four fuel slug
>   tanks in the ship's power core give her an increased range, even at
>   extreme speeds and engine temperatures. While repairs to her various
>   systems must usually be performed each time the ship lands, she
>   refuels at an average rate of only once per month.

---

The [Millennium Falcon Owner's Workshop Manual](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Millennium_Falcon_Owner's_Workshop_Manual) factbook offers the following comparison.

**"Stock" Model - Max speed (atmospheric) = 500mph** 
[image]

**Falcon - Max speed (atmospheric) = 650mph**
[image]

Comment: The second point is supported in "Star Wars: Absolutely Everything you need to know"

Comment: @Edlothiad - Actually it's a little more accurate. It says 65**2** MPH. Close enough though...

Comment: I've never heard of a "light-speed plus point one" hyperdrive before, does that still jive with the more recent 'class 2 hyperdrive' listed in your second source?

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh - There's no specific speeds given for hyperspace travel. .1 is *quite* fast, .5 is very much faster.

Comment: Is 0.5 faster than 0.1?  In the above, it looks like the MF has 0.5 hyperdrive primary, with 10 as backup.  And the stock model has 2 primary, 12 backup.  These numbers seem to suggest that lower is better; so 0.1'd be better than 0.5, right?

Comment: @Nat - Lower is better, yes. Apparently only military ships have anything less than a class 1 since lower numbers are illegal. However, a "plus point one" is apparently less fast than a "plus point five". If you're looking for consistency, you might prefer a different sci-fi film series :-)